# LineageOS で RasPi 向けの3.5インチモニターを使いたい

Tags: android, raspberry-pi

LineageOSをインストールしたラズベリーパイで、こちらの商品を使いたいです。

(amazon.co.jp) [ブランド: LOTW

For Raspberry Pi 4 ディスプレイ 3.5 インチ LCD モニターTFTスクリーンタッチスクリーンそしてケース ヒートシンク](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B07YJBG1ZM/)

ページの下の方の説明書に書いてあったのですがどうやらドライバが必要らしいです。
https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show

LineageOSにドライバを入れる方法がわかる方いましたら教えてください。
よろしくお願いします

Comment: 製品ページや GitHub の説明を見る限り、あくまで **Linux ベースのシステム向け** のようです。Android は別物と考えるべきです。(少なくとも Windows は非対応と明言されています)

Comment: Raspberry PI対応の OSは Linuxが多く, LCD-showでは xserver-xorg なども含まれ X11なのでしょう (あるいはテキストベース？)。Androidは Linux kernel使ってるけど SurfaceFlinger ディスプレイサーバーで, X11ドライバーは使えない

Comment: ありがとうございます

Comment: (high-speed SPIとDSI混同したコメント書いてました, ので削除)。"Working:" で SPIがあるので表示かどうかは別としてそのうちSPIは使えそうだけど [LineageOS 19 (Android 12L)](https://konstakang.com/devices/rpi4/LineageOS19/)